# How to create encrypt / decrypt function using AES in php and call that function from another file

Tags: php, encryption

This is my service layer which includes Encrypt function..

```
class profileService{   

public function passEncrypt($userarray){

$password->setPassword($userarray['password']); 

$plaintext = 'My secret message 1234';
$password = $password;
$method = 'aes-256-cbc';

// Must be exact 32 chars (256 bit)
$password = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);
echo "Password:" . $password . "\n";

// IV must be exact 16 chars (128 bit)
$iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

// av3DYGLkwBsErphcyYp+imUW4QKs19hUnFyyYcXwURU=
$encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
return $encrypted;
// My secret message 1234
//$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

echo 'plaintext=' . $plaintext . "\n";
echo 'cipher=' . $method . "\n";
echo 'encrypted to: ' . $encrypted . "\n";
//  echo 'decrypted to: ' . $decrypted . "\n\n";
}
}
```

This is my DAO layer which calls encrypt function

```
    $profile = new profileService();
    $pass_password= $profile->passEncrypt($userarray);

    try {            
        $conn = $connection;

        // our SQL statements

        $Pass_user_id = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM tb_user")->fetchColumn();

        echo "User Last Id from User Table" . $Pass_user_id;
        if (!$Pass_user_id) {
            die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
        } else {
        $sql="INSERT INTO tb_password ( user_id, email,password, status)
        VALUES ('$Pass_user_id', '$pass_email','$pass_password','$pass_status' )";
        $conn->exec($sql); 
        }

        return 1;     

    }catch (PDOException $e )  {
       /* if ($conn->isTransactionActive())  // this function does NOT exist
            $conn->rollBack(); */
            echo $e;
            throw $e;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to look at Sodium. It is a new extension added to PHP, basically providing a modern interface to best-in-class cryptography functions.

In your code, you are doing a lot of things yourself, like constructing an initialization vector. This is the type of thing you really want to get right, so using the PHP built-in functionality is usually a way safer option. Especially considering that the IV should be unique for every time you encrypt something - so your code exposes a fatal lack of understanding of how cryptography is supposed to work. I strongly recommend you stick to using libraries instead of trying to implement these fairly complicated concepts yourself.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php
And: https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/04-secretkey-crypto.md#crypto-secretbox (from the author of PHP's Sodium integration)